# Double Pressed needed when using DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

Okey, my problem is that I need to double tab everything on the screen to do something. Like if I press the back button only once I can’t see that anything happens. Anyone know something about this problem?

It’s the same with all buttons on the screen, but if I click all the buttons once I’m able to just click once on the button to make anything happen!

Hope that you understand my question otherwise comment!!

### EDIT

If I use my phone there is no problem with the back button but with the buttons.. I set the buttons to activ(true) and the item to android:state_activated and its activated. But the really weird thing is that once i press the back button once the activated button is activ as it should!!

### CODE(XML)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.kandidat.datx02_15_39.tok.layout.AddDietActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can i see the xml of the layout ?

Comment: Fixed it! the problem was that i had a searchView that took the focus and the layout didnt update

Comment: Can you put the answer in the answer box provided and then accept your won answer by ticking the box? This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.